# Based on the Android Touchpaint Sample, how do I save the output?

Tags: android

I have run the [Touchpaint sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html), and it just allows you to draw with different paint functions, what it does not allow is to save what you draw on the phones memory so you can retrieve it later on.

How would i do this, i would really apprecciate if you could help me in any way you can, i am also looking at making the interface, ( the surface where the drawing takes place) to be flicked, what i mean by this is that instead of going to a new convas or deleteting what you may have done, you just flick it up or down and a new convas appears.

How would i do these two things, with the touchpaint code already available.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Call buildDrawingCache() on the PaintView, then save the Bitmap returned by getDrawingCache() to the sdcard.
2. Sounds like you want to implement GestureDetector.onFling()?